# Identifying a quotient module with a submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring (not necessarily commutative etc). Let $M$ be a left $R$-module and $N\subset M$ a submodule of $M$. Consider the quotient $M/N$, is there a natural way to identify via an isomorphism (of $R$-modules), say, the quotient $M/N$ to a submodule $M_{1}\subset M$ of $M$?

EDIT: $M\subset R$.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that in the special case where R is a principal ideal domain, and M is a torsion module, every quotient of M is isomorphic to a sub-module of M and vice-versa. This follows (non-trivially in my opinion) from the decomposition of M into cyclic sub-modules (see the exercises at the end of chapter 3.9 of "Basic Algebra I" by Jacobson). In particular, this result holds for every finite abelian group, which at least to me is not obvious.

Comment: Would you mind me asking how you know this to be true? (When R is a principal ideal domain and M is torsion module.) I can't see how the decomposition into cyclic-submodules implies this @ChenVanDram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no in general.

Take as a counter-example $R=M=\mathbf Z$, and $N$ a non-trivial ideal $n\mathbf Z$ ($n\ne 0,\pm1$). Then $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ is a *torsion* module, whereas any submodule of $\mathbf Z$, i.e. any ideal of $\mathbf Z$, is *free*.

Comment: @Xuqiang QIN: Great minds think together… ;o)

Comment: Thank you. Okay now supposing we have $M \cong N \oplus M/N$, is there a way now?

Comment: Absolutely: compose the canonical injection of $M/N$ into the direct sum  by the inverse isomorphism.

Comment: Apologies but what do you mean by canonical injection of $M/N$?

Comment: $m+N\mapsto(0,m+N)$. It has nothing to do with quotients, only with the notion of direct sum.

Comment: @Bernard :)    You noted the case when n=1 or -1, which I missed.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think in general the answer is no.

Think about the example of $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and let $M=R$ as an $R$ module. Since $R$ is a PID, all ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ (in this case submodule of $M$) are $n\mathbb{Z}$,isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

But all the nontrivial quotients of $\mathbb{Z}$ are like $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. They are not free.

Edit: for the last line, exclude case $n=1$ or $-1$ or $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You also missed n=0. ​ ​